# Laravel prevent url to be escaped in blade window.location

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a button that downloads a file when clicked, like this.

```
<?php
    $file = public_path('storage\excel.xlsx');
?>
{{$file}} //this prints C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\public\storage\file.xlsx 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-add-data" data-toggle="" data-target="" onclick="window.location='{!! $file !!}'"> Download File </button>
```

When I use `onclick="window.location='C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\public\storage\file.xlsx'"` it works fine.

But when I use the above code it fails throwing error `SyntaxError: malformed hexadecimal character escape sequence`.

I suppose this is because the backslash causing it to try escaping the string.
I already tried using `{!! $file !!}` and setting it to `(string)` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: try use \\ instead of \

Comment: Try: `{{ $file }}`

Comment: Why do you want the file location to open? It won't for others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use this from Laravel 5+

```
<a href={{ asset($file) }}>Download</a>
```